# NuSOAP PHP web service and sending large string

Tags: php, nusoap

again i am seeking for you help! I am new to NuSOAP, so please bear with me. I am trying to send multiple records, with multiple columns to my service, split this into records and writting them into my sql table.

For example, i have a batch that updates my variable like so (records are separated with ";", columns inside records are separated with "¤")

Name1¤Surname1¤Date1¤number1;Name2¤Surname2¤Date2¤number2;Name3¤Surname3¤Date3¤number3 ...

I have a simple function which accepts this variable. *(1st of all i dont know if sending a string is optimal ... I read that i should be sending an xml document ...)*

So if i declare a new variable inside my script and past the exact value that my program sets up, execute the script, everything works! Records are written in a table without any problem. I wrote up to 500 records. The problem is when i call my webservice ... In that case i get an error:

"SOAP Fault: error in msg parsing: XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Invalid character:"

I think i am sending a to many chars in my variable ... Again i am new to NuSOAP and i am trying to figure this out based on an example i found online ...

When i was sending just text with only 1 delimeter, i was able to sent and write 500 records. The variable was setup like so:
TEST001;TEST002;TEST003; ...;TEST500

And the web service recieved the variable and wrote all 500 records to the table. Can someone please help me out or tell me the correct way of doing this?

Regards,
HEki

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$server = new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("test"."urn:test");
$server->register(
            "service",
            array("variable_text"=>'xsd:string'),
            array("return"=>"xsd:string")
        );
        
function service($variable_text)
{
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "root";
    $mysql_database = "service";

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    
    $response='START';
    
    // Connect to database server

    $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    
    $token = strtok($variable_text, ";");
 
    while ($token !== false) 
        {
            $data = explode('¤', $token);
            $data0 = $data[0];
            $data1 = $data[1];
            $data2 = $data[2];
            $data3 = (int)$data[3];
            $strSQL = "INSERT INTO test (column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES ('".$data0."','".$data1."','".$data2."', '".$data3."')";
            mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
            $response='NEW';
            $token = strtok(";");
        }   

    // Close the database connection

    mysqli_close($con);

    return $response;
    
}
        
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

Comment: Not sure, but it may be that the `¤` character is causing the problem.  Try changing it to something else (just a simple char like `+`).  Although it would be better to send the data with a proper data structure.

Comment: @NigelRen you are right!!!!!!! Switched it to | and its working!!!

Like i said ... i am new and new stuff are not done the proper way. Can you, please, point me into the rection how to send it as proper data structure?

Thanks a milion!!!!

Comment: Generally, JSON is the most popular and widely used format, followed by XML when communicating via a web API. I would recommend JSON because most programming languages have built-in ways to decode and encode JSON. You just have to structure your data to fit this format. See [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).